# How to take the raw header from fiddler and post to http webRequest

Tags: c#, httprequest, fiddler

When I look in fiddler RAW data, I see about 15 lines of data that goes to the server. I want to play that back exactly like fiddle does when I say replay request.  I don't just want to add headers, but want the full request to go back. That is, I want to push something like what I have below (in c#).

Any suggestions?

```
POST https://www.smith.com/account/signin?returnurl=%2Faccount%2Fsignin%3Freturnurl%3D%252F HTTP/1.1
Host: www.smith.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 81
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: https://www.smith.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://www.smith.com/account/signin
Accept-Encoding: 
...
```

Comment: You can just send the text using regular sockets... That's going to be the easiest way to send an exact duplicate.

Comment: You could try to copy the exact RAW data into [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en).

Comment: You didn't specify why you don't want to simply replay in Fiddler by pressing "R" or using the Composer. But assuming you want this in a C# app or something, simply download the RequestToCode extension for Fiddler, which outputs your requests as .NET code.

Comment: thanks Eric.  Very nice.  "RequestToCode".  what a concept :).  I'd really like a "RequestToBuildTheRestOfMyApp" also.